# PostgreSQL 9.6 View Performance & Side Effects

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Our project makes use of different schemas to keep things organized and secure. We `GRANT` access to entire schemas rather then selecting individual components which may result in an inadvertent leak of data. Additionally, it would make our lives easier if we could write our queries from a single schema as it would help with maintainability and error reduction.

For example, `schema_foo` and `schema_bar` contain raw normalized data (not accessible to the end user) and `schema_baz` contains functions (accessible to the end user) that return data from `schema_foo` and `schema_bar`. This makes sense when data in `schema_foo` and `schema_bar` need processing prior to delivery to the end user; however, in some cases no additional processing is required.

In this case, would it make sense to make a view in `schema_baz` simply calling the table in `schema_foo` or `schema_bar` and if so, what is the performance difference / side effects between

```
SELECT * FROM schema_foo.table_bin;
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW schema_baz.view_bin AS SELECT * FROM schema_foo.table_bin;
SELECT * schema_baz.view_bin;
```

If this is acceptable, is it better (for any reason) to identify each column by name rather then `*`?

**Note:** The resulting view would also be used in other queries. I know the query planner is great; however, I'm concerned there could be unintended consequences of (ab)using views for the sole purpose of making a table accessible from another schema.

Answer (score 2):

My experience leans towards "If in doubt, be explicit". Using `select *` in a production system is usually just asking for trouble down the road.

Also, adding columns to the base table(s) in Postgres won't change the columns in the view-- they won't magically appear. As an example:

```
(postgres@lh:5432) # create table foo (col1 integer, col2 text);
CREATE TABLE

(postgres@lh:5432) # create view bar as select * from foo;
CREATE VIEW

(postgres@lh:5432) # alter table foo add col3 date;
ALTER TABLE

(postgres@lh:5432) # insert into foo values (1, 'One', current_date);
INSERT 0 1

(postgres@lh:5432) [~] # select * from foo;
 col1 | col2 |    col3    
------+------+------------
    1 | One  | 2017-08-17
(1 row)

(postgres@lh:5432) # select * from bar;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 | One
(1 row)
```

This was with version 9.5 but I would be surprised if other versions worked any differently.

Comment: wow... this is an exceptional response. If you have any insight into the first part of the question (the appropriateness of views to make a table accessible from another schema) I would love to hear it.

Comment: @losthorse -- I don't think performance would be an issue (though setting up a test to verify that wouldn't be the worst idea to come along). The larger issue in my mind would be maintainability of the system (how many schemas/views are involved, how often do they change, will there be other views built on top of the "synonym views", etc.)-- if that isn't an issue then ... sure, why not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tables can and do change, often. If you simply write *, then what if a column gets added or deleted in the base table? Your view changes without your knowledge.

It is best practise to always list out column names when writing views of any kind.

Comment: This seems like a reason to use `*` as we would not want to have to make the same change in multiple places. The view in this case in only to make the table accessible from a different schema.

Comment: Why would you need to make a change in multiple places? You are only creating the one view, right? If you are saying that when the base table changes, you don't want to have to change the view, that is unfortunate. You can use * in that case, but it is not best practise. In this scenario, it doesn't sound like it matter all too much to be honest.